# no such module 'Firebase' in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been looking up on every website that had a similar/identical issue to this Xcode error and I have tried everything and nothing has worked. Most people say cleaning and building the project will make Firebase recognized but that hasn't worked. I've tried a bunch of different framework search paths but each framework is in a different folder, not one framework folder. This is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Target' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

 # Pods for Target

  target 'TargetTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
    # Pods for testing
 end

end
```

[these are my project folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw5Ho.png)

i've tried making my framework search path $(SRCROOT) and all variations and nothing works. My issue seems to be unlike any other that I can find from googling. I suspect its the framework search path but i don't know what to make it, and I could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried in target> embedded binary with library.. I mean you added framework??

Comment: Are you definitely looking at the .xcworkspace file and not the .xcproj file?  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Also, this is an obvious one but... you did run 'pod install' right?

Comment: I am in the .xcworkspace and i ran pod install already, no luck so far :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Promposal

target 'Promposal' do

    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'

    # Pods for testing
 target 'PromposalTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
 end

end
```

You were writing your `podfile` properly and you were adding the `Firebase` only to the `test`. Try this `podfile` and check.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. When I did pod install in terminal it told me "The `Promposal [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Promposal/Pods-Promposal.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target." I changed my Framework Search Path to $(inherited) and that got rid of the error. Now I am on to a new but hopefully less difficult error, "Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Firebase>'"

Comment: This new error is a result of my line of code "var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://my-url.firebaseio.com")" where my-url is a real url

Comment: Instead of  `var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"my-url.firebaseio.com")` ,try `var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` .

Comment: Thank you again! This works. I don't know if you will have an answer for this, but do you know where there is a tutorial on using Firebase now that it is updated and previous syntax is no longer valid? It seems this Firebase update is brand new and a lot of the tutorials online use the old, no-longer-valid syntax such as var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"my-url.firebaseio.com")

Comment: It's all there in the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start#set_up_firebase_database). Going through it should help you code better.

Comment: what is PromposalTests??

Answer (score 0):

It was good for me:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
   pod 'Firebase'
end

target 'TargetName' do
   shared_pods
end

target 'TargetNameDev' do
   shared_pods
end
```